# Variable's value doesn't change in C program

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, struct

i'm writing a project for my university. There is function in this problem that i must implement. In this function i must allocate memory for an array of structs, and every time the arrays fills i must reallocate the array with double space. Every struct has two members. The first member is a char pointer where i must enter a string. I must keep doing this until the user enter END as string input. After that, i must free the memory that is allocated and isn't used. For example, let's say that i have 16 structs allocated and i used only 10. I must free the memory for the rest 6 structs. I did all this, except for the part that i must free the memory. Ι have a variable in which i keep the record of how many structs used. My problem is in this variable. For some reason, the value of this variable stays the same. I spent a couple of hours trying to find the reason but i can't understand why this happens. I also searched and i didn't find anything similar that solves my problem. Here is my code. I would appreciate your help.

```
struct nameInfo {
char *name;
char *replacement;
```

};

```
nameInfoT *readNames(int *megethos) {

nameInfoT *infos;
int i = 0; //metriths pou deixnei se poio struct tou pinaka infos anaferomaste
char formatstr[15], buffer[SIZE];
int current_size = 0;
int initialized_structs = 1;
nameInfoT *tmp;

sprintf(formatstr,"%%%ds", SIZE -1);

infos = (nameInfoT *)malloc(sizeof(nameInfoT));
if (infos == NULL) {
    printf("There was a problem allocating memory\n");
    exit(1); //epistrofh se periptwsh pou den mporei na ginei dianomh mnhmhs.
}
for  (i = 0; ;i++) {
    scanf(formatstr,buffer);
    if (strcmp(buffer, "END") == 0) {
        break;
    }


    if ((current_size == initialized_structs) && (initialized_structs != 1)) {
        initialized_structs *=2;
        tmp = realloc(infos, (sizeof(nameInfoT) * 2 * initialized_structs));
        if (tmp == NULL) {
            printf("Error allocating Memory");
            exit(1);
        }
        infos = tmp;
        initialized_structs *=2;



    }


    infos[i].name = strdup(buffer);
    if (infos[i].name == NULL) {
        printf("There was a problem allocating memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    current_size++;

}

printf("Initialized structs number is: %d", initialized_structs);
*megethos = current_size; // anathesh sthn timh tou pointer pou tha epistrafei mesw twn parametrwn,
                            //to plhthos twn structs pou xrhsimopoiountai

return infos;
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  There are a number (actually, probably rather a large number) of questions essentially the same as this. Some of them may even be in the list of related questions on the right (I can see at least 5 plausible contenders in the list shown to me).  Please try to find an answer in those.  I observe that you are not testing that `scanf()` actually reads data; that is a problem. Starting with `initialized_structs = 1` when there is no initialized struct is worrisome; you should start with 0, but use a formula such as (2*N+2) or (2+N)*2.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment and your recommendation. I did what you suggest and actually i think it's much better now. I searched before i post. My actual problem isn't how to create and allocate a dynamic array of structs. My problem was why the variable initialized_structs didn't change value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to make your code more organized and readable, with clearly different sections and functions for different purposes.

This block of code seems wrong to me:

```
if ((current_size == initialized_structs) && (initialized_structs != 1)) {
    initialized_structs *=2;
    tmp = realloc(infos, (sizeof(nameInfoT) * 2 * initialized_structs));
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating Memory");
         exit(1);
    }
    infos = tmp;
    initialized_structs *=2;
}
```

The condition `(initialized_structs != 1)` doesn't allow to ever execute this code because `initialized_structs` is 1. Also you are calling `initialized_structs *=2;` two times, which is only correct because the realloc takes *four* times the current_size (you've already doubled `initialized_structs` before the realloc and then you multiply it again by 2).

It should be something like this:

```
if (current_size == initialized_structs) {
    initialized_structs *= 2;
    tmp = realloc(infos, (sizeof(nameInfoT) * initialized_structs));
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating Memory");
         exit(1);
    }
    infos = tmp;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was trying different solutions and one of them is to change the location of where i multiply initialized_structs *=2. I just copied the code from xCode and i didn't notice that i forgot to delete the one statement. As for my problem, you are right. the one condition in in if statement is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is

```
  && (initialized_structs != 1)
```

I'm not sure why you have it, but since `initialized_structs` is only changed inside that block and is initialized to `1`, that condition must *always* fail.

---

On an unrelated note, you actually quadruple the allocated memory every time.